# How to write quotes inside quotes - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to define block of html `$result_html="";` to use inside the shortcode like this:
`[ms-protect-content id="7001"]' . $result_html . '[/ms-protect-content]`

I am trying to define the following html as a $result_html:

```
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" value="<?php _e( 'Send Enquiry', 'wc_enquiry_form' ); ?>" class="button" />
</p>

<?php do_action( 'product_enquiry_after_form' ); ?>
```

I ran into the problem with correctly writing the quotes inside the quotes.

I know that I should add a backslash `\` before the quotes to escape them, but in this case it is just getting a way to confusing for my understanding of php.

My code currently looks like this with my corrections:

```
$result_html='        
<p>    
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" value="<?php _e( \'Send Enquiry\', \'wc_enquiry_form\' ); ?>" class="button" />
</p>
<?php do_action( \'product_enquiry_after_form\' ); ?>
';
```

According to Dreamweaver, there are no errors, but when the code is rendered, it is not correct, the `<?php echo $post->ID; ?>` is not passing, but I can't find my errors.

Can someone please correct me, thanks

btw, I changed from `$result_html="";` ( double quotes ) to `$result_html='';` ( single quotes ), not sure if it's ok

Comment: It's explained with details and examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: @axiac yes this has nothing to do with Wordpress and everything to do with basic quoting of strings in PHP, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental lack of understanding about how quoting works in php. There is no reason for you to have php opening and closing tags inside of single quotes!

Let me know how this works.

```
$result_html='        
<p>    
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' .$post->ID . '" />
<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" value="' .  _e( 'Send Enquiry', 'wc_enquiry_form' ) . '" class="button" />
</p>' . do_action( 'product_enquiry_after_form' );
```